# JQuery: intercept click submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jstl

I have this piece of code to intercept the click of a submit button but does not work at all

**JS**

```
$('#deleteDescriptionButtonId3').click(function () {
    alert('deleting description...');

    $('#productFormId').attr('method', 'post');
    $('#productFormId').attr('action', '/nicinc/desc/del/3');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="descriptions0.text" name="descriptions[0].text" class="form-control" rows="4"> 
    ASDADS
</textarea>
<span class="clear space10">&nbsp;</span>
<button id="deleteDescriptionButtonId3" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
    Delete description
</button>
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: why not use `$(yourForm).on("submit", () => {})` and just leave the button how it is?

Comment: Have you a form to submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.preventDefault();`

Here is an example

```
$( "#deleteDescriptionButtonId3" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  alert('deleting description...');

    $('#productFormId').attr('method', 'post');
    $('#productFormId').attr('action', '/nicinc/desc/del/3');
    $('#form_id').submit();
});
```

Here #form_id is the form that you are submitting

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?